# Rerank documents in elastic

Tags: elasticsearch, search-engine, reinforcement-learning

I am working on a project, where each user has a set of documents, and wants to retrieve the best ones with a query.

I already have an algorithm which sort my documents from a user query. Because I use semantic comprehension in my query, I am kind of cautious with it and I want to be more aggressive on the top results.

So my idea was to use a reinforcement algorithm, which takes user query and already sorted documents, and then make a reranking on those ones. Then I'll use user reactions to results, to design a reward function (still in research).

One of my coworker came up with another idea, which was to use [ranking evaluation api](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-rank-eval.html#search-rank-eval) of elastic. The problem, from what I read, is that each query help to make the same query better for the next user. But we have completely separated user environment and I felt like this was better suited for search engine with the same document space (like google or Wikipedia).

The only question I would need answer is, did I understand ranking evaluation API well and is it true that one query only help the same query, or is there another way to use it for my purpose (semantic reranking)?

And if you have further knowledge, is my idea to use reinforcement learning a good one or should I use something else?